# Is there Ruby library like Clojure's Schema for validating data structures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clojure

I really like [Prismatic's Schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) for validating data structures. However I find myself working in Ruby right now, and I'm trying to generate a bunch of models from either YAML or JSON for testing in our Rails app. I need to be sure that the data coming in from YAML/JSON is semantically correct, for example certain values in a hashmap must be boolean, or a string, or an array of strings, etc.

Example of the data I'm working with (in Ruby notation):

```rb
@@data = [
  {name: "United States",
   states: ["New York", "New Jersey", "Texas"],
   default_tax: false},
  {name: "US Remote",
   states: ["Alaska", "Hawaii"],
   default_tax: true}
]
```

What's the best Ruby-esque way to do this? Can someone recommend a library analogous to Schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, it looks like [`hash_validator`](https://github.com/JamesBrooks/hash_validator) is the best one out there.

Usage is straight-forward. Adapting the example in the github repo to my data above:

```rb
# Validations hash
validations = 
  name:        'string',
  states:      'array',
  default_tax: 'boolean'
}

validator = HashValidator.validate(@@data[1], validations)

validator.valid?
  # => true
```